# Inserting date as integer (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code to concatenate a values from different columns. One of the columns; column M - is date, in format dd/mm/yyyy. I would like to concatenate the integer value of date of this with other values in cells.

I am trying to use `Int(CDbl("date"))` to convert the date value to int, then use that to concatenate with other cells.

My current vba code is:

```
Dim datevar As Integer
For i = 1 to LastRow
    datevar = Int(CDbl(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 13).value))
    target.location.formula = "=Project_Name!B" & i & "&UPPER(Project_Name!D" & i & ")&Project_Name!E" & i & "&Project_Name!F" & i & "&Project_Name!G" & i & "&Project_Name!H" & i & "&Project_Name!I" & i & datevar & ""
Next i
```

When I run this, I get a "Type Mismatch" error on the `datevar = Int(CDb1(...))` line:

[image]

Can someone please advise why I am getting an error, and if there is a more efficient way of working?

**EDIT**

OKay - I get the error as CDbl cannot convert String to Double... However, the value in that cell is definitely a date and not string. What is the best way to counter this issue?

Comment: If you use `=ISNUMBER()` on that cell, does Excel return TRUE? If not, Excel isn't recognizing it as a valid date, which means it is a string, and that string can't be converted directly to a double. A test on my system (using the system date format of `mm/dd/yyyy`) with `01/01/2018` in cell A1 and `=IsNumber(A1)` in cell B1 says `TRUE`.

Comment: Couls you change it to Double instead of Integer?

Comment: @KenWhite - dammit it is returning False.... But when I click on format, it is recognised as date format....

Comment: If your goal is to concatenate the value with other values, why not leave as string and use string operations to remove the '/'s ? You will then have a string with numerical characters

Comment: @Kubie - you are a genius.. That was exactly what I was thinking!!!

Comment: Excel stores dates as numbers. `Integer` won't fit modern days, so you better use `Long`. If you need string representation, use `Format` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with dates, you better store their value to `Double` and not `Integer`.

Just use:

```
datevar = Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 13).Value
```

You can add the following line to protect against none-integer values:

```
If IsNumeric(Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 13).Value) And Sheets("Project_Name").Cells(i, 13).Value > 0 Then
```

---

**Note**: you can use `Double` or `Long` to store date values.
`Integer` is limited to values up to 32,767, read [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/data-type-summary).

If we look at today's date, Aug-17-2018 value is 43,329, which is over the `Integer` upper limit, that's why you are getting your error.

Comment: Yes - I would agree, but for operational reasons, I am required to convert the date into an int so we can generate a unique id..

Comment: @OdaySalim I would recommend using `Long` and not `Integer`, read here. And with that, the code above will still work the same

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on our conversation in the comments, heres a quick little example of that idea:

```
Sub test()

    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim spaceSpot As Integer

    cellValue = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value) ' which is 12/22/2018
    spaceSpot = InStr(cellValue, " ")

    ' Checking if date is in format 12/22/2018 00:00:00
    If spaceSpot > 0 Then
        cellValue = Left(cellValue, spaceSpot - 1)
    End If

    cellValue = Replace(cellValue, "/", "")

    MsgBox cellValue ' shows 1222018

End Sub
```